# Xamarin API VK List forming

Tags: c#, json, linq, http, json.net

I'm trying to do qualification job for a work and have some problems with realization of code on Xamarin.
I have such classes and functions. They're working on console of c# but not in xamarin. I don't know what to do. They give only freeze on Xamarin.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace radacode.ActionForm
{
class ListMaker
{
    public static List<Country> GetCountryList()
    {
        List<Country> result=new List<Country>();
        Task<string> task =GetRequestAsync(@"http://api.vk.com/method/database.getCountries?need_all=1&v=5.60");
        JObject vk = JObject.Parse(task.GetAwaiter().GetResult());
        foreach (JObject jsonCountry in vk["response"]["items"])
            result.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Country>(jsonCountry.ToString()));
        return result;
    }

    public static async Task<string> GetRequestAsync(string url)
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            return await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
    }
    public class Country
    {
        public int Cid { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        override public string ToString()
        {
            return Title;
        }
    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

When using Xamarin Forms, it's best to use Portable Class Projects rather than Shared.  In my opinion.

Also it's important that Statics are not used especially for calls that are async.  Think of Async as to being similar to AsyncTask in JAVA.  They're none blocking.

```
public class ListMaker
    {
        public List<Country> GetCountyList()
        {
            return GetCountryListAsync().Result;
        }

        private async Task<List<Country>> GetCountryListAsync()
        {
            var result = new List<Country>();
            var task =
                await GetRequestAsync(@"http://api.vk.com/method/database.getCountries?need_all=1&v=5.60");

            var vk = JObject.Parse(task);

            foreach (var jsonCountry in vk["response"]["items"])
                result.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Country>(jsonCountry.ToString()));
            return result;
        }

        private async Task<string> GetRequestAsync(string url)
        {
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
                return await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
        }

        public class Country
        {
            public int Cid { get; set; }
            public string Title { get; set; }

            public new string ToString()
            {
                return Title;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now that you have your class, you can then create an instance of it and execute it.

NOTE:- the Async and Await in my example, or this one, is incorrect.

It should really bubble up to a parent class that has a property and a void in the class statement.

```
public async void TheLister()
{
    var listMaker = new ListMaker();
    var countryList = await listmaker.GetCountryListAsync();

    // Do something with countryList
}
```

Comment: Also look for JSON.NET which can be installed via Nuget (under tools) that will do the serialisation and deserialisation for you although it will add a 100 ms to do it for you.

Comment: Sorry it's my first post on stackoverflow and I'm trying to write shortly. I have added some corrections which you have highlighted. I have used Newtonsoft JSON. But any of this fix didn't help with my problem. I have freezed program in Xamarin. Usage of this class in console c# app giving expected result - list of countries. I hope u can understand me. English is not my native lang

Comment: There is problem to connect app to the internet. Program is freeze on response getting

Comment: I'll type this in, are you using Xamarin Forms with a portable class project with this code in it?

Comment: I'm using Xamarin Forms with shared class project

Comment: This should work with shared as well, especially if you use TheLister()

Comment: I can understand way in which way work async & await. I use my code for downloading country list given in response only, I have tried to use System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString for my target but I have errors, because this class cannot be used in all app types.

Comment: Let's start from main target. I need to download response from GET request in Xamarin. How can I do this?